# I2C devices not detected on Pi Zero

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to connect an OLED screen to an RPI zero through I2C.
They look a little out of date, but I followed the instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/04/i2c-oled-display-module-with-raspberry-pi/) (more or less), but

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

Doesn't find anything... In fact, it doesn't *do* anything: it wants to be run as root, but then it doesn't find anything...

I've tried

```
lsmod | grep i2c
i2c_bcm2835             6465  0
i2c_dev                 6706  0
```

Now I'm stumped...

Comment: More info at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=235716

Comment: Maybe stupid question. Did you enabled i2c in raspi-config?

Comment: I have at least six of these units in various sizes, as well as SPI ones. Either your i2c isn't configured on the Pi, or you're mis-wiring the unit. Worst case, the unit is broken.

Comment: Make sure I2C is enabled in `raspi-config`.

Comment: There is no such animal as a stupid question: I have missed the bleedin' obvious so many times...
But not this time, I think.
For clarity, by the way, i2cdetect run as root gives a table full of dashes. I think this means that i2c is working.
Wiring is the next obvious answer, I've checked & double checked that...

Comment: Tried the same SD card, same screen & same wiring (but not the same wires) on a different Pi and it worked fine...
I doubt that it's the wires, but I'll try that next, but later.